# Generic class: referencing type specific method

Tags: java, generics, methods, reference, abstract

I have a bounded generic class, let's call it Generic, with a parameter T that extends an abstract class Abstract:

**Generic Class:**

```
public class Generic<T extends Abstract> { 
   
   public <T extends Abstract> List<T> method() {
   
      Map<String,String> map = T.getMap(); //this is the line with the error. I'll explain it below

      //return statement and such
   }
}
```

**Abstract Class**

```
public abstract class Abstract {
   protected Map<String, String> map;

   public abstract Map<String, String> getMap();
}
```

**The class referenced by T in the generic class**

```
public class class1 extends Abstract {
   
   public class1() {
   //map is inmutably defined here and assigned to the super
   }

   @Override
   public Map<String, String> getMap() {
   return super.map;
   }
}
```

When trying to reference the method getMap() which comes from a class inside bounds of T (and which all possible instances of T will have, per the abstract class definition, I get the following error:

*non-static method getMap() cannot be referenced from a static context*

Yet there are no static keywords anywhere. What am I missing??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because the method `getMap()` is  an *instance* method (ie not `static`), you need an *instance* if `T` to call the method on.

---

Your class hierarchy looks off too. I think you actually want something more like:

```
public class Generic<T> extends Abstract<T> { 

}

public abstract class Abstract<T> {
    protected Map<String, T> map;
}
```

but without context of your intention, I can't be sure.

Comment: Yes, I simplified the whole thing for clarity. In my project there is an abstract class called "Material" and a bunch of materials with similar fields and operations inside those fields, that all extend the Material class. 

I'm trying to code some DB operations (the generic class) common to all materials with a single class. The map here is a HashMap<String, String> for all the materials. 

Do you have any advice to improve my structure?. Also, is there a way to declare an instance of T inside the generic class? I tried T t = new T(); but of course it didn't work. 

Thanks!

Comment: Better to post a  simplified version of your actual code - it will make more sense to  readers. If you have a compile error, ask here. If you are asking for a review or your approach, ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com